# Streaming with Videos app fills Other memory

Tags: ios, video, ipad

Recently I bought a film in iTunes and streamed it using the Videos app. Afterwards I found that my 'Other' memory usage had jumped massively (to the point I couldn't watch or download anything else).

I do know that when I download films and then manually erase them the memory is reclaimed.

Eventually I had to back up the iPad, erase and restore it. This is a very drastic fix every time I watch a film! Is there any other way to force the Videos app to remove the streamed film from memory?

Comment: there is an Answer here that might work for you https://discussions.apple.com/message/23111042

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same Issue and was a long time in contact with Apple Developers over the Apple Bugreporter. At the moment there is no "fine" way to delete the "Others" Memory on your Device.

My Bug is marked as Dublicate - so we only can hope for an Apple Solution.

I'll stay tuned and but here some news (if there are some)